# Specify order of import for multiple tables in R

Tags: r, import, text-files

I'm trying to read in 360 data files in text format. I can do so using this code:

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.txt")
myfiles = lapply(temp, read.table)
```

The problem I have is that the files are named as "DO_1, DO_2,...DO_360" and when I try to import the files into a list, they do not maintain this order. Instead I get DO_1, DO_10, etc. Is there a way to specify the order in which the files are imported and stored? I didn't see anything in the help pages for list.files or read.table. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

`lapply` will process the files in the order you have them stored in `temp`.  So your goal is to sort them the way you actually think about them.  Luckily there is the `mixedsort` function from the gtools package that does just the kind of sorting you're looking for.  Here is a quick demo.

```
> library(gtools)
> vals <- paste("DO", 1:20, sep = "_")
> vals
 [1] "DO_1"  "DO_2"  "DO_3"  "DO_4"  "DO_5"  "DO_6"  "DO_7"  "DO_8"  "DO_9" 
[10] "DO_10" "DO_11" "DO_12" "DO_13" "DO_14" "DO_15" "DO_16" "DO_17" "DO_18"
[19] "DO_19" "DO_20"
> vals <- sample(vals)
> sort(vals) # doesn't give us what we want
 [1] "DO_1"  "DO_10" "DO_11" "DO_12" "DO_13" "DO_14" "DO_15" "DO_16" "DO_17"
[10] "DO_18" "DO_19" "DO_2"  "DO_20" "DO_3"  "DO_4"  "DO_5"  "DO_6"  "DO_7" 
[19] "DO_8"  "DO_9" 
> mixedsort(vals) # this is the sorting we're looking for.
 [1] "DO_1"  "DO_2"  "DO_3"  "DO_4"  "DO_5"  "DO_6"  "DO_7"  "DO_8"  "DO_9" 
[10] "DO_10" "DO_11" "DO_12" "DO_13" "DO_14" "DO_15" "DO_16" "DO_17" "DO_18"
[19] "DO_19" "DO_20"
```

So in your case you just want to do

```
library(gtools)
temp <- mixedsort(temp)
```

before your call to `lapply` that calls `read.table`.

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly to keep all the files in the appropriate order.